# I want to get specific posts from Instagram based on tags or hashtags and display them in my website

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I am working on a client building a website using react js, i want to get access to its Instagram posts and display them in a section of the website but I want specific posts, the client wants only to display events. Can i get a little help on the flow and whats the best practice to achieve this? Thanks in advance!